# Convert List to single string

Tags: c#, linq

trying to convert a List property to string, any ideas?

```
public class ContactLog
{
     public string To { get; set; }
     public string Message { get; set; }

     public string FormattedMessage
     {
         get { return To+ ',' + Message; }
     }
 }

public void SendBatch(List<ContactLog> logs)
{
    //Problem Line
    string messages = CreateBulkMessage(logs.Select(o => o.FormattedMessage));
}
public string CreateBulkMessage(string message)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to *serialize* your list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `string.Join` to combine the results of your `Select` into one `string`:

```
string messages = string.Join(", ", logs.Select(o => o.FormattedMessage));
```